# Best way to reclaim the disk space consumed by chaindata downloaded mist/geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, light-clients

When I tried out the wallet `mist` and `geth`, I wasn't aware of the `--light` option. Therefore the applications have downloaded the full chain to my local MacbookPro (`macos`).

It is now sitting at 45.5Gb.

I would like to be able to reclaim the space.

Here is my plan:

1) Shutdown the applications `mist` and `geth`

2) Remove all files under `~/Library/Ethereum/geth/chaindata/`

3) Start geth with `geth --light --rpc`

4) Start mist with `mist --rpc http://localhost:8545`

Is this plan reasonable? Is there any potential pitfall?

Answer (score 1):

Decempber 5 Pető Zoltán @micahaza states that the --light mode is buggy and not to use it on the [Mist Gitter channel](https://gitter.im/ethereum/mist).  It seems that the problems with light sync are causing low network usage.